# Esper - handle out of order events

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I want to monitor if an event does NOT arrive within 10 minutes of arrival of event with the same `id`.

This is the EPL I am currently using:

> SELECT * FROM pattern[ every s=`Order_Status`(status="placed") -> (timer:interval(600 sec) and not e=`Order_Status`(status="delivered", id=s.id))]

Usually `placed` event arrives before `delivered`, but sometime because of some lag in our systems, `delivered` event happens to come before `placed` for some `id`.

Cases

1. time: 8:00 event: Order_Status{id=167, status="placed"}
   time: 8:07 event: Order_Status{id=167, status="delivered"}

   > < No alert > (delivered within 10 minutes)
2. time: 8:00 event: Order_Status{id=189, status="placed"}
   time: 8:17 event: Order_Status{id=189, status="delivered"}

   > < Alert> (delivered after 10 minutes)
3. time: 8:00 event: Order_Status{id=2637, status="delivered"}
   time: 8:08 event: Order_Status{id=2637, status="placed"}

   > < Alert > (but shouldn't alert, the problem is `delivered` event for this `id` has arrived before `placed`)

As stated, I would get a false alert as the EPL pattern starts the window after the `placed` event and waits for  `delivered` event which has already arrived.

How do I handle this scenario of out of order events ?

Note:
(Basically I want to check for every `id` if the time difference between `placed` and `delivered` is above a certain threshold.
I also have the timestamp fields inside each event)

Answer (score 0):

You have a "not" in your pattern that is used to detect the absence of events. Your requirement doesn't search for absence so the "not" isn't right.

There is a requirement questions as well. You don't state what happens when there are many A events and just one B event. Are there many matches or just the match for the last A event or the first A event or something else?

Sample pattern:

```
pattern [A -> (timer:interval(10 minutes) and B)]
```

Or this is a join that would seem to match what you want:

```
select * from B unidirectional, A#window(10 minutes)#lastevent
```

The "A#window(10 minutes)#lastevent" keeps the last event for up to 10 minutes.

Comment: sorry my bad, actually I have to detect absence of event so "not" is fine in query. And the identifier in the stream is `id`. So I want to check if for a given `id`, `delivered` did NOT come within 10 minutes of `placed` (for the same `id`). And how do i handle the out of order in this scenario ?